# Someone/thing that a responder responds to is called?

Tags: word-request

I know a **Responder** is a person or something that responds to a specific thing.

But what do we call a person or thing that a responder responds to? I think it's something with "respond" or "response" as its root.

Comment: This has become common to describe the emergency services.  The 'first responders".  So the person on the receiving end is usually referred to as a victim or casualty.  You could try using respondent or respondee but folks will assume you are conducting an interview.

Comment: I see you’re active on StackOverflow. Are you asking in the context of programming?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what the person or thing is. It could be an emergency, an event, a message, a question, etc.

"Prompt" might be a good general noun to describe most cases, but it is not universal. For example, referring to a natural disaster as a "prompt" for first responders would be odd.